# Continuity of Left Inverse

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be an injective continuous function between metric spaces and $f(X)$ be dense in $Y$.  Clearly $f$ has a left-inverse but does it have a continuous left-inverse?

Comment: $\mathbb Q \to \mathbb R$

Comment: But why is this a counter-example?  If $i:\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is the inclusion (for example) then its inverse on $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is the identity; hence is continuous from $\mathbb{Q}$ to itself.  Therefore, by the Tietze extension theorem, we then have the existence of a continuous extension to it.  Hence, it $i$ admits a continuous inverse in this case.   Replacing $i$ by more general injective maps with those domains should be the similar.

Comment: Tietze requres $\mathbb Q \subset \mathbb R$ to be closed, it is not closed. There is no continuous map $\mathbb R \to \mathbb Q$ that is the identity on $\mathbb Q$, because $\mathbb Q$ is not connected and $\mathbb R$ is. In fact, $\mathbb Q$ is totally disconnected, so the only continuous functions $\mathbb R \to \mathbb Q$ are constant.

Comment: Oh true.  Do you know of a necessary and sufficient condition for a continuous left inverse to exist?  (But not necessarily a homeomorphism).

Comment: There are examples where $X=Y$ and $f$ is a continuous bijection but $f^{-1}$ is not continuous.

Answer (score 2):

Take for example $f : [0,1) \to S^1, f(t) = e^{2\pi i t}$. This is a continuous bijection but certainly $f^{-1}$ is not continuous. Thus, even if $f(X) = Y$, the answer is in general "no".

A neccesary conditon for the existence of a continuous left inverse $g : Y \to X$ is $f(X) = Y$, i.e. that $f$ is a *bijection*. Too see this, let $y \in Y$. There exists a sequence $(y_n)$ in $f(X)$ such that $y_n \to y$. Letz $x_n \in X$ be the unique element such that $f(x_n) = y_n$. Then $x_n = g(f(x_n)) = g(y_n) \to g(y)$ by continuity of $g$ and $y_n = f(x_n) \to f(g(y))$ by continuity of $f$. By the uniqueness of limits in metric spaces we conclude $y =  f(g(y)) \in f(X)$.

A sufficient  criterion for the existence of a continuous left inverse is that $f$ is a bijection and $X$ is compact.